# Tensorflow error : unsupported callable - (from ex ???)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to adapt the CNN of the tutorial "[Build a Convolutional Neural Network using Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn)" to a dataset of mine, and don't know how to fix this error

...well the input files should be fine, as they are already tested and ok, as I am currently running them on another CNN but much much different (it's working fine but I'm willing to change it, adding some extra features like the "dropout")

The fact is that the error (I use Spyder as IDE) is quite meaningless. I have done some tries to see where the error it is but I'm slightly getting more and more confused, so let's try to ask you guys

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

#----- global variables Start ------
nb_of_neurons=1024
model_learning_rate=0.001

#----- global variables End ------

def run_cnn(mymode, last_date, names, mydata, mylabels, run_id):
    def cnn_model_fn(cnndata, mylabels, mode):
      input_layer = tf.reshape(cnndata, [-1, 4, 5, 1])
      conv = tf.layers.conv2d(
          inputs=input_layer,
          filters=16,
          kernel_size=[2, 3],
          padding="same",
          activation=tf.nn.relu)
      print(conv.shape.dims)
      pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
      pool_dims=pool.shape.as_list()[1]*pool.shape.as_list()[2]*pool.shape.as_list()[3]
      pool_flat = tf.reshape(pool, [-1, pool_dims])
      dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool_flat, units=nb_of_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
      dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
          inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
      logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=2)
      predictions = {
          "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
          "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
      }
      if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

      loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=mylabels, logits=logits)
      print(loss)
      if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=model_learning_rate)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
      eval_metric_ops = {
          "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
              labels=mylabels, predictions=predictions["classes"])
      }
      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
          mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


    if mymode == 'TRAIN':
        mode= tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
        cnn_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
            model_fn=cnn_model_fn(mydata, mylabels, mode), model_dir="/sess")

        tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}

        logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
            tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

        train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            x=mydata,
            y=mylabels,
            batch_size=100,
            num_epochs=None,
            shuffle=True)

        cnn_classifier.train(
            input_fn=train_input_fn,
            steps=1,
            hooks=[logging_hook])
        cnn_classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)

    elif mymode == 'PREDICT':
        mode= tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT
        cnn_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
            model_fn=cnn_model_fn(mydata, mylabels, mode), model_dir="/sess")

        tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}

        logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
            tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

        eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
                x=mydata,
                y=mylabels,
                num_epochs=1,
                shuffle=False)
        eval_results = cnn_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

    else:
        print('**** ->***   ????   ***')
```

This is called as a module from another python script which passes to all the input data, as follows:

1. mymode: in ['PREDICT', 'TRAIN']
2. last_date: not relevant
3. names: not relevant
4. mydata: np array of shape (3195,20), of values in [0., 1.] (float)
5. mylabels: np array of shape (3195,), of values in [0, 1] (int)
6. run_i: not relevant

Finally, the error appears after the train_op (i.e. in the `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)`), as follows:

```
...
  File "C:\Users\Fulviooo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\function_utils.py", line 56, in fn_args
    args = tf_inspect.getfullargspec(fn).args

  File "C:\Users\Fulviooo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_inspect.py", line 216, in getfullargspec
    if d.decorator_argspec is not None), _getfullargspec(target))

  File "C:\Users\Fulviooo\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1095, in getfullargspec
    raise TypeError('unsupported callable') from ex

TypeError: unsupported callable
```

I hope that someone can enlighten me about where's the error and how to fix it.
Furthermore, I'd be pleased to receive any other suggests for improvements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the problem is that this estimator is quite rigid and expects variables with predefined names and formats.
ie setting up the expected names:

```
train_data=mydata
train_labels=mylabels
```

and formats (dict):

```
x={"x": train_data}
```

then it runs